# How to find users who had only error for certain event?

Tags: splunk

We have log entries in format like this:
LogLevel=info  username=some1 eventID=update

So in case of error the LogLevel will be LogLevel=error 
LogLevel can also be debug

What I need to do is to find all users that had eventID=update but always had LogLevel=error and present them in table format 
Username | count

If I simply search

```
eventID=update LogLevel=error | stats count by username
```

then I will get all matching entries for users with LogLevel=error but some of these users probably also had entries with LogLevel=info (or debug)
How do I find users that had only LogLevel=error with this eventID in a given time period?

Answer (score 0):

Splunk has an implicit `AND` between the expressions before the first pipe so there should be no LogLevels other than error in your results.  You can verify that with this query:

```
eventID=update LogLevel=error | stats count by LogLevel
```

which should report a single number for LogLevel=error.

Comment: The query will return events with LogLevel=error this is true, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to find users that had ONLY error for the LogLevel. In other words if same user had events with LogLevel=error and info then I don't want to get such user is result

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you're trying to do.  Try this query:
`eventID=update LogLevel=* | stats count(eval(like(LogLevel,"error"))) as Errors, count(eval(Not like(severity,"error"))) as Other by username | where Other==0 | fields - Other`.  The idea is to count both error and non-error then show the users who don't have any non-errors.